# Can a student in the USA with part-time work authorization work remotely for a UK company?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, work

Can an international student studying in the USA with part-time work authorization work remotely for a firm in the UK? It is possible or does one need a UK work visa as well?

Comment: You won't need a UK visa unless you plan to go to the UK.  But this is a question for [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Oh. Thank you. Wasn't sure which group this was a right question.